# AS3 Event listener for typing in textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, addeventlistener, typing

When I type in the textfield I want an event listener to start. But I only want it so when you start typing, not when you click on it. Im not too sure how to go about this. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

`TextField`s dispatch two events which would be helpful for achieving that:

[`Event.CHANGE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event%3achange)
[`KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3akeyUp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`KeyboardEvent.Key_UP`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#KEY_UP)

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    // do something
}
```

If you need to know what character was typed, look at [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#keyCode)